# Atualizar commits para considerar alterações no .gitignore

Tags: git, github

Estou com a seguinte situação:

Criei um repositório `git` a partir de um remoto do **Github**.

Fiz vários `commits` no repositório local (sem fazer `push` para o remoto).

Quando fui realizar `push` para o remoto, ele foi rejeitado porque tem arquivos maiores que 50MB.

Então, alterei o `.gitignore` para ignorar os arquivos maiores de 50MB (não preciso deles no repositório remoto).

Fiz um novo `commit` com a alteração no `.gitignore`.

Mesmo assim, ainda ocorre a rejeição dos arquivos grandes (>50MB).

Encontrei algumas respostas que falam em `reset` mas tenho receio de fazer isso, pois não posso perder o trabalho já feito.

Como faço para "atualizar" os `commits` para que considerem a alteração do `.gitignore` que exclui os arquivos grandes e enviar o `push` para o repositório?

Answer (score 2):

Após mais algumas horas de pesquisa, encontrei a solução em [Removing sensitive data from a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository)

`git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all`

onde `PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA` é o caminho para os arquivos a excluir dos commits.

Depois de atualziar o `.gitignore`, bastou fazer um novo commit e executar:

`git push origin --force --all`.

Answer (score 1):

`git rm --cached <arquivo>` remove o arquivo do repositório (o git entao deixa de trackear esse arquivo), porém ele permanece no seu espaço de trabalho. É muito comum usar esse comando após adicionar um arquivo no `.gitignore` e você quer removê-lo do repositório uma vez que já foi commitado. É a abordagem mais utilizada e bem segura.

É importante lembrar de usar o `--cached`, pois apenas `git rm` remove o arquivo completamente. Sugiro também dar uma lida na própria [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm).

Comment: Obrigado @Igor Cavalcanti, mas já havia tentado esta solução e não deu certo. De qualquer maneira, ontem à noite passei mais algum tempo pesquisando a documentação do Github e encontrei algo que funcionou.